# BotBuilder-Location & bitwise operators

Tags: botframework, bitwise-operators

I use BotBuilder-Location often and it works fine but I don't understand how it checks the required fields.
I'm not too much of an expert in bitwize operators:

> requiredFields:
>                   locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.streetAddress |
>                   locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.locality |
>                   locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.region |
>                   locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.postalCode |
>                   locationDialog.LocationRequiredFields.country

If I go to `node_modules/botbuilder-location/lib/dialogs/required-fields-dialog.js` I can see this self-invoking function:

```
(function (LocationRequiredFields) {
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["none"] = 0] = "none";
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["streetAddress"] = 1] = "streetAddress";
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["locality"] = 2] = "locality";
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["region"] = 4] = "region";
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["postalCode"] = 8] = "postalCode";
    LocationRequiredFields[LocationRequiredFields["country"] = 16] = "country";
})(LocationRequiredFields = exports.LocationRequiredFields || (exports.LocationRequiredFields = {}));
```

Can you explain in bare outlines  how does it work?
I checked here and also BotBuilder-Location documentation and issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 things going on here:

1. This code is originally written in typescript and is then converted into javascript.  javascript does not have enums.  So when the typescript enums are converted into javascript they become hashmaps which is what you are seeing in the function in your question.
2. the numbers associated with each field has been chosen so it can fall into a group of bits.  see how they follow the 0 1 2 4 8 16.. pattern that you would See in a byte? This is so that they can be "packaged" into a smaller package (such as a byte) for validation.  I'm not exactly sure how it works here, but for example, if all the required fields were filled the bits would be 111111 or decimal 31.  if the bits sent are not 31 there would be a field that is required that is not filled.

Hope this helps.